# Is it proper coding to return null on an indexer if index doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, indexer

I add an indexer to my class. Is it proper coding to return null when the index doesn't exist? Then the consuming class would always have to check for null too. Is there a more elegant way?

```
public class ObjectList
{
    private readonly ArrayList _objectList = new ArrayList(); 
    public void Add(object value)
    {
        _objectList.Add(value);
    }
    public object this[int index]
    {
        get 
        {
            if (CheckIndex(index))
                return _objectList[index];
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckIndex(index))
                _objectList[index] = value;
        }
    }
    private bool CheckIndex(int index)
    {
        if (index >= 0 && index <= _objectList.Count - 1 )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public int IndexOf(object value)
    {
        return _objectList.IndexOf(value);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var oList = new ObjectList();
        oList.Add("Some String");
        oList.Add("new string");
        //oList[1] = "Changed String";
        Console.WriteLine("Index of new string = " + oList.IndexOf("new string"));
        Console.WriteLine("Index of Some String = " + oList.IndexOf("Some String"));
        Console.WriteLine("index 0 = {0} and index 5 = {1}", oList[0], oList[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Non-existing index 5 doesn't lead to crash when written to the console = {0} ", oList[5]);
        if(oList[5]!=null)
            Console.WriteLine("But when GetType is called on non-existing index then it crashes if not intercepted.", oList[5].GetType());

    }
}
```

Also I wonder why doesn't the program crash when I write the value of an element to the console when it is null.
If I do not check for null when calling GetType() on it then it crashes, however.
How come?

Comment: What language is that supposed to be? Looks similar to Java, but it isn't...

Comment: if this is suppose to be a library, throw `IndexOutOfRange` exception. Also, `Console.WriteLine` must be checking for null BEFORE performing any operation with the null object. But since you're not checking while calling `GetType` method over the object, you get the exception.

Answer (score 1):

the is "It depend"

1- when you build a libarary (for example DLL) and this dll is used by software that you do not know at all, or it is not already exits.
then the better is to throw an expcetion as the following

```
public object this[int index]
{
   get {
      if (index >= 0 && index <= _objectList.Count - 1 )
          throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

     // your logic here .....
    }
 }
```

2- but if you build just a small class to use from anther place.
so you can follow the first way or you can return null.

```
public object this[int index]
{
   get {
      if (index >= 0 && index <= _objectList.Count - 1 )
          return null;

     // your logic here .....
    }
}
```

and at that time you have to check the reference which returned by the indexer
but ( i prefer the first way, it is more clean)

Answer (score 1):

The most normal way would be to throw an [IndexOutOfRangeException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx). This is what the .NET builtin containers do, and many might expect the same behavior from a similar interface. As one might say, "it is better to ask for forgiveness than for permission."

However, the `ArrayList` object you use internally will already throw this if you try to access an invalid item. In addition, this overhead for bounds checking is already automatically done by the `ArrayList` itself, and so, in this situation, the index accessors should be simple wrappers around the `ArrayList`.

Another situation might be: What if I add `null` to your object? How could I then tell if an object I try to get in the future doesn't exist, or is just the value `null`? Exceptions fix this by interrupting the code flow so you can write code with the *assumption* that the code will work, but that you know what to do in the case of failure.